# How to extract true positives data (complete row with data) after training and testing from test dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

How do you extract true positive data from testing data after training and testing?

For example, in the test data, I have two rows and one row is true positives and the other is false negatives. However, I would like rows which only have true positive values. How do you extract the complete row from the testing data after training and testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is browse your prediction vector, get the indexes of "1" responses, and then check those indexes in `y_test`. if your `y_test[index]` is also a "1" class, then select the row by index in `X_test`

I tested this, it works for me. In my case, my `X` and `y` are `pandas.DataFrame`.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    import numpy as np
    
    X_train = pd.read_csv("saves/cv_sets/X_train1.csv", sep=";", encoding="latin1")
    X_test = pd.read_csv("saves/cv_sets/X_test1.csv", sep=";", encoding="latin1")
    y_train = pd.read_csv("saves/cv_sets/y_train1.csv", sep=";", encoding="latin1")
    y_test = pd.read_csv("saves/cv_sets/y_test1.csv", sep=";", encoding="latin1")
    
    clf = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced", solver='lbfgs', C=0.1)
    model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    pred1 = np.where(pred==1)
    
    TP_Indexes = []
    for k in pred1[0]:
        if(y_test.iloc[k][0] == 1):
            TP_Indexes.append(k)
    
    
    X_test_TP = X_test.iloc[TP_Indexes]
```

Comment: Can you please write code for that I'm confused

Comment: "pred1 = np.where(pred==1)" --> This line is for selecting the lines your model predicted as 1, so if you want fn or tn, change to pred==0. "y_test.iloc[k][0] == 1" --> This line is for selecting lines on your dataset that are real 1, so if you want fp or tn, change it to == 0. (also, accepting the answer would be appreciated ;) )

Comment: Thanks man and do you know how to assign back categorical variables to main data after training and testing? (using Inverse_transform)

Answer (score 0):

If you use label binarization function from scikit learn for encoding the labels before training then it has a built in inverse_transform function  Please go through this link /https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html/